# Digitally sign XML using smart card in Silverliight web application

Tags: xml, silverlight-4.0, digital-signature

XML files are stored on the server and need to be signed by the user via smart card which will not run in out-of-browser mode.

Do I need to use outdated CAPICOM (for instance via javascript and HTML Bridge) or I could use dotNet classes  ?

I know I could just send message digest and let the user sign it. In that case, is there any code I could look at. The problem here is to make sure that the XML is verifiable by 3thd party tools since any slight change of scheme will make it fail.

Is there any other option I could look into ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With silverlight in web browser you won't get access to user's certificates (neither in Windows certificate storage nor in other places). In our distributed signing solution (which you can use as well) we offer ActiveX control, Flash applet and Java applet - they all offer more  than Silverlight can.